# JSON nested object reduce or flatten

Tags: javascript, json

I need to flatten this JSON to have no nests just shellfish and then the name of it etc. Thanks in advance! I tried a few things so maybe reduce or map but I don't know enough about those to attack the problem, any online resources specific to problems like this you guys can share? I work with these a lot would be very handy to master!

```
"data": [
        {
            "name": "Batch1",
            "description": "seed",
            "age": 2,
            "quantity": 1000,
            "source": "Hatchery",
            "hatchery": "robs hatchery",
            "location": "dingle",
            "shellfish": {
                "name": "oyster"
            },
            "grade_list": {
                "name": "Grade0"
            },
            "stock_type": {
                "name": "seeds"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Batch2",
            "description": "Batch2",
            "age": 20,
            "quantity": 15700,
            "source": "aka",
            "hatchery": "aka",
            "location": "dingle",
            "shellfish": {
                "name": "oyster"
            },
            "grade_list": {
                "name": "Grade1"
            },
            "stock_type": {
                "name": "mature"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "5555",
            "description": "45",
            "age": 1,
            "quantity": 134,
            "source": "fhh",
            "hatchery": "hfhj",
            "location": "garden",
            "shellfish": {
                "name": "oyster"
            },
            "grade_list": {
                "name": "Grade0"
            },
            "stock_type": {
                "name": "seeds"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Edit: I need this to have no nests and look like this:

```
"data": [
        {
            "name": "Batch1",
            "description": "seed",
            "age": 2,
            "quantity": 1000,
            "source": "Hatchery",
            "hatchery": "robs hatchery",
            "location": "dingle",
            "shellfish": {
                "name": "oyster"
            },
            "grade_list": {
                "name": "Grade0"
            },
            "stock_type": {
                "name": "seeds"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Batch2",
            "description": "Batch2",
            "age": 20,
            "quantity": 15700,
            "source": "aka",
            "hatchery": "aka",
            "location": "dingle",
            "shellfish": {
                "name": "oyster"
            },
            "grade_list": {
                "name": "Grade1"
            },
            "stock_type": {
                "name": "mature"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "5555",
            "description": "45",
            "age": 1,
            "quantity": 134,
            "source": "fhh",
            "hatchery": "hfhj",
            "location": "garden",
            "shellfish": "oyster",
            "grade_list": "Grade0",
            "stock_type": "seeds"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is invalid JSON. JSON cannot start with `"data": `. Probably some braces missing. Moreover, if you have this data structure in JavaScript, don't tag this as `json` (read the usage description).

Comment: *"Thanks in advance"*: hold on... what is the problem? Can you edit your question and add your attempt and what problem you have with it?

Comment: What's the expected output? Your description is ambiguous: *"I need to flatten this JSON to have no nests just shellfish and then the name of it etc."*

Comment: hey guys sorry I will edit the qs now!

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous posted 2 times now and no answers had to re-post the qs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this process more automated for all the elements of your array you can use the map to change all the elements that have the prop `name`.

```js
const response = {
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Batch1",
      "description": "seed",
      "age": 2,
      "quantity": 1000,
      "source": "Hatchery",
      "hatchery": "robs hatchery",
      "location": "dingle",
      "shellfish": {
        "name": "oyster"
      },
      "grade_list": {
        "name": "Grade0"
      },
      "stock_type": {
        "name": "seeds"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Batch2",
      "description": "Batch2",
      "age": 20,
      "quantity": 15700,
      "source": "aka",
      "hatchery": "aka",
      "location": "dingle",
      "shellfish": {
        "name": "oyster"
      },
      "grade_list": {
        "name": "Grade1"
      },
      "stock_type": {
        "name": "mature"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "5555",
      "description": "45",
      "age": 1,
      "quantity": 134,
      "source": "fhh",
      "hatchery": "hfhj",
      "location": "garden",
      "shellfish": {
        "name": "oyster"
      },
      "grade_list": {
        "name": "Grade0"
      },
      "stock_type": {
        "name": "seeds"
      }
    }
  ]
}

const result = response.data.map((element) => {
  const keysWithNameProp = Object.keys(element).filter(key => element[key].name !== undefined);
  const copyOfElement = {...element};
  keysWithNameProp.forEach(prop => {
    copyOfElement[prop] = element[prop].name;
  })
  return copyOfElement;
});

console.log(result);
```

Is this code the first thing is done is to have the list of all the keys that have the `name` prop. With that list now I can iterate over it and change the object prop to use just the value of the `name`.

Comment: hey another question, if the shellfish was ''species'' instead of name and the other two were ''name'' how would I tweak the function so it flattens both of those objects? Thank you

Comment: @MichalKubiak is this case you need to check if the object have `name` or `species` property. You can have this with `element[key].name !== undefined || element[key].species !== undefined` is the `filter` callback. The last thing would be change the attribution value in the `forEach` with `element[prop].name || element[prop].species`.

Complete Code: https://gist.github.com/mathiasgheno/7ce4e5c4323efb63e0a955191ce76c43

Answer (score 1):

This will flatten any sub-object into a single key-value pair; it will *only* work if the sub-object has the single key "name" containing the intended value.  Comments in the code explain how it works:

```js
const data = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "Batch1",
      "description": "seed",
      "age": 2,
      "quantity": 1000,
      "source": "Hatchery",
      "hatchery": "robs hatchery",
      "location": "dingle",
      "shellfish": {
        "name": "oyster"
      },
      "grade_list": {
        "name": "Grade0"
      },
      "stock_type": {
        "name": "seeds"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Batch2",
      "description": "Batch2",
      "age": 20,
      "quantity": 15700,
      "source": "aka",
      "hatchery": "aka",
      "location": "dingle",
      "shellfish": {
        "name": "oyster"
      },
      "grade_list": {
        "name": "Grade1"
      },
      "stock_type": {
        "name": "mature"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "5555",
      "description": "45",
      "age": 1,
      "quantity": 134,
      "source": "fhh",
      "hatchery": "hfhj",
      "location": "garden",
      "shellfish": "oyster",
      "grade_list": "Grade0",
      "stock_type": "seeds"
    }
  ]
}

const transform = (input) => {
  // step through each object in the array
  for (obj of input.data) {
    // step through each key in the object
    for (k of Object.keys(obj)) {
      // if that key contains an object:
      if (typeof(obj[k])==='object') {
        // replace the object with its own 'name' field
        obj[k] = obj[k].name
      }
    }
  }
  return input
}

console.log(transform(data))
```